# Using twitCurl how do I pass parameters to twitter URLs

Tags: twitter

I need to access the Twitter API for a quick project I am working on and not wishing to get too tied up in learning the API I thought [twitCurl](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/) would be the ideal solution.

At the moment, all I need to do is get the latest mentions for a Twitter user, which [twitCurl](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/) can do very easily and takes care of all the oAuth stuff into the bargain.

But I now want to use the 'since_id' parameter in my call to the API. I can see no way to do this with [twitCurl](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/), and in fact there seems to be no way to pass parameters to many of the [twitCurl](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/) calls. Am I missing something or is this something seriously lacking from [twitCurl](http://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/)?

If this is not possible then can someone suggest and alternative C++ wrapper for the Twitter API.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like to answer my own question but I have fixed it and just in case anyone else has the same problem I will document it here.

I modified the twitCurl code to add an extra parameter, a string to represent the 'since_id'. It was really straightforward in the end and I have submitted the changes to the twitCurl developers. Here is my diff of the changes if you can't wait:

```
Index: twitcurl.cpp 
=================================================================== 
--- twitcurl.cpp        (revision 25) 
+++ twitcurl.cpp        (working copy) 
@@ -474,19 +474,28 @@ 
 * 
 * @description: method to get mentions 
 * 
-* @input: none 
+* @input: sinceId - since_id in string format 
 * 
 * @output: true if GET is success, otherwise false. This does not 
check http 
 *          response by twitter. Use getLastWebResponse() for that. 
 * 
 *--*/ 
-bool twitCurl::mentionsGet() 
+bool twitCurl::mentionsGet( std::string sinceId ) 
 { 
     bool retVal = false; 
     if( isCurlInit() ) 
     { 
+        /* Prepare URL */ 
+        std::string buildUrl( "" ); 
+        buildUrl = twitterDefaults::TWITCURL_MENTIONS_URL; 
+        if( sinceId.length() ) 
+        { 
+ 
buildUrl.append( twitCurlDefaults::TWITCURL_SINCEID.c_str() ); 
+            buildUrl.append( sinceId.c_str() ); 
+        } 
+ 
         /* Perform GET */ 
-        retVal = 
performGet( twitterDefaults::TWITCURL_MENTIONS_URL ); 
+        retVal = performGet( buildUrl ); 
     } 
     return retVal; 
 } 
Index: twitcurl.h 
=================================================================== 
--- twitcurl.h  (revision 25) 
+++ twitcurl.h  (working copy) 
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@ 
     const std::string TWITCURL_EXTENSIONFORMAT = ".xml"; 
     const std::string TWITCURL_TARGETSCREENNAME = "? 
target_screen_name="; 
     const std::string TWITCURL_TARGETUSERID = "?target_id="; 
+    const std::string TWITCURL_SINCEID = "?since_id="; 
 }; 
 /* Default twitter URLs */ 
@@ -123,7 +124,7 @@ 
     bool timelineFriendsGet(); 
     bool timelineUserGet( std::string userInfo = "" /* in */, bool 
isUserId = false /* in */ ); 
     bool featuredUsersGet(); 
-    bool mentionsGet(); 
+    bool mentionsGet( std::string sinceId = "" ); 
     /* Twitter user APIs */ 
     bool userGet( std::string& userInfo /* in */, bool isUserId = 
false /* in */ );
```